# git rebase pulls in changes from unrelated branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm something of a newbie so don't laugh too hard...

I did some work on branch A and made a few commits.  Then, had to make a hotfix change so I created branch B and changed a few files.  Then, because master didn't change I thought it would be simpler and clearer if I did:

```
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge B
```

But, this applied changes from branch A.  What am I not understanding? This can't be the way it's supposed to work, is it?

Answer (score 0):

When you created branch `B`, you were on branch `A`, so the base of your branch `B` contains all the work you did in branch `A`.  This is why those branch `A` changes are now in `master`.  Diagramatically, you have the following situation:

```
branchA: A -- B -- C
branchB: A -- B -- C -- D
```

The correct strategy to making a hotfix in `master` would be to create a branch from `master`:

```
# assuming you start on branch B
git checkout master
git checkout -b master_hotfix
# make the fix
git commit -m 'made the hotfix'
git checkout master
git merge master_hotfix
# carry on as you were
git checkout branchB
```

To undo what you have done, you can try resetting your `master` branch to the commit before the erroneous merge took place.  Type `git log` and count how many commits came in frok the merge with `branchB`.  Then type:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~N
```

where `N` is the number of commits you wish to remove from `master`.  Then apply the steps I gave above for correctly making the hotfix.  Note that you should not use `git reset` if you have already pushsd your local `master` to the remote.  In this case, you could try using `git revert`, but it might just make sense to leave `master` the way it is, and just merge `branchB` again later once you have completex your work there.

Comment: You are correct.  Looking back over my shell history, that's exactly what I did.  I thought I was going insane there for an hour or so.